# Reading parameters from jsp page in the server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

In my Spring project, my service classes are capturing the parameters I send from my forms via method POST this way, currently:

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_fornecedor')")
public boolean cadastra(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String identificador = request.getParameter("identificador");
    String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
    String website = request.getParameter("website");
    String[] endereco2 = request.getParameterValues("endereco[]");
    String[] contato2 = request.getParameterValues("contato[]");

    Fornecedor f = new Fornecedor();
    f.setRazao_social(nome);
    f.setWebsite(website);
    if(identificador.length() == 14)
        f.setCnpj(identificador);
    else if(identificador.length() == 11)
        f.setCpf(identificador);

    List<Endereco> lista_endereco = new ArrayList<Endereco>();
    if(endereco2 != null) {
        int max = endereco2.length;
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            int id = Integer.valueOf(endereco2[i]).intValue();
            lista_endereco.add(endereco.findById(id));
        }
        f.setEndereco(lista_endereco);
    }


    List<Contato> lista_contato = new ArrayList<Contato>();
    if(contato2 != null) {
        int max = contato2.length;
        for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            int id = Integer.valueOf(contato2[i]).intValue();
            lista_contato.add(contato.findById(id));
        }
        f.setContato(lista_contato);
    }

    return fornecedor.persist(f);
}
```

I am trying find another way to read this parameters, without the need of read one by one with the method getParameter (or getParaterValues).

Each service class is related to one of my Entity classes, the name of the fields from form have the same name of the atributes in the table, and all of them which are arrays, are lists of primary keys to another entity.

Anyone knows if exist any solution where I could use the information above to read this parameters all at once?

(I trying create a generic class for my controller and service classes to group this commons methods. I wonder if exist a way to do that without direct reference to the names of each parameter.)

I prefer a solution where no other framework besides Spring be used.

Comment: Check out the `@RequestParam` annotation. It works for both single values, arrays and lists

Comment: But with @RequestParam I will need list each parameter separately (I already used this option in other projects). I am trying find a solution where I don't need even know the list of parameters (the method just need try associate this list with the atributes from entity class - as I say, the parameters have the same name from the tables in the database).

Comment: If you create a DTO (or perhaps just use your entity class) and use it in the controller method, Spring will try to bind the request parameters to the properties of the DTO. Perhaps that is what you are looking for

Comment: can you give an example for that?

Comment: Check out http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use your Entity to pass the parameters.

You mentioned you already have Entity classes for the forms, then you should be able to use

```
@ModelAttribute(value=" ")Entity entity
```

to get all the form parameters, and then you pass this entity to your service method as a parameter?

Comment: Do you know what parameter I should use for option 'value' of ModelAtribute if I am implementing the controller as a generic class? Right now, I have this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871541/non-constants-values-for-atribute-of-the-annotations-modelatribute-and-preauto