# Atribute for annotations @ModelAtribute and @PreAutorize in Generic Controller / Service classes

Tags: java, spring, generics, annotations

I am trying setting a generic class for my project. So far I get this code:

https://github.com/klebermo/blog.cms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/config/generic/controller/GenericController.java

In this moment, I am stuck with this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(service.cadastra(object))
        return "yes";
    else
        return "not";
}
```

the parameter for the annotation ModelAtribute should be the name of an entity class from my project, which I have stored in the class member entity_class, but can't use because the annotation only accept constant values.

Also, I have this same problem with the annotation PreAutorize. I will use this annotation like that:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, '<<permission_name>>')")
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra")
public ModelAndView cadastra() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("privado/"+this.entity_name+"/cadastra");
    return mav;
}
```

and in my methods from my generic service too. The permission name follows this rule:

```
<<action_name>>_<<entity_name>>
```

and for each entity class I will have three permissions: cadastra (new_item), altera (change_item) and remove (remove_item).

Anyone can point a direction of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question `@ModelAttribute`, what I've understood, you have several form calling the same Mapping method cadastra to verify if the informations are correct. 
I think you can use a form parameter to tell which entity class it is, and use wrapper to wrap all of the entities that call this method.

create an Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Wrapper{
private Entity1 e1;
.....
```

in your jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="wrapper" .../>
<form:hidden value="classname" .../>
<form:input path=e1.someProperty .../>
```

in your controller:

```
@RequestParam("classname") String classname;//used to get which entity it's
service.cadastra(wrapper.getEntityX())
```

for the second question I don't know much about @PreAuthorize annotation.

Comment: In fact, I have several form each one call the method cadastra of a specific controller, each one of them being derived from this class. So, yes, all call this method, but each one already calling it with the correct Entity name. I want be able to use this name with ModelAtribute (and PreAuthorize). My problem with creating a class named 'Wrapper' it's if I create another entity, probable a new unwanted table will be created in the database.

Comment: sry, it doesn't have to be an Entity, just like a domain class with private attributes and Getter&Setter. And the value in @ModelAttribute has to be constant, which means even if it's a variable, it has to be final static. Well, i'm interested in this problem too.